# Unable to Install ANT to clone library of Volley

Tags: java, android, git, ant, android-volley

I am unable to Install ANT, but i get install GIT, so i make a Folder in C Drive and paste the ANT unzipped files.

I have following location of installations,

```
1) JAVA: <D:\jdk1.7\bin> 
2) GIT : <C:\Program Files\Git\bin> 
   AND
3) i created a Folder in C Drive for ANT : <C:\ant\bin>
```

Using Command prompt ,

i can execute the the command git , successfully . But when i put command ant, gives the following error

```
      Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar 
      Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! 
      Build failed
```

My environment variable set to the following path,

```
ANT_HOME = <c:\ant\bin> 
JAVA_HOME = <d:\jdk1.7\bin> 
Path = <%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;>
```

That's all , Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, Just download the project given in the link below ,

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java_Free_Code/Image/Download_Volley_demo_Free_Java_Code.htm

And import using Eclipse, and RUN. That's all . no need to make git reference. ( if you getting error continuously )

volley.jar you can use in your custom projects also.

Answer (score 1):

According to the information you provided, PATH variable should look like following:

```
%JAVA_HOME% ; %ANT_HOME% ; <other entries>
```

It seems that you're using Windows, thus you should check both your user-scope and system-scope environment variables (Computer - Properties - Advanced System Settings - Environment Variables).

Currently your build is failing due to JRE-related entry in PATH variable. Please remove it and retry.

Easiest way to check that the issue is resolved is to execute this from your command line:

```
javac -version
```

Normally this will give output like following:

```
javac 1.7.0_40
```

Answer (score 0):

Install java and add it to class path by either creating java_home or directly to path variable in windows. Do the same thing for ant too. ie) place the ant location[upto ant\bin] in path variable and open the command prompt type ant . you will get the output as build failed which expects build.xml. Same will be applicable for git and other utilities... 
hope it helps

Comment: i set CLASSPATH also , But it is not working . Can u tell me what location should be set as CLASSPATH ? i have researched a lot , not getting solution.

Comment: which class r u trying to set in Classpath?

Comment: i used set classpath=D:\jdk1.7

Comment: set the java path upto D:/jdk1.7/bin/ in path. you can type javac in cmd to check whether the java is set or not. Same thing you can do it for ant.